# jQuery(document).on("keydown",...) works, but not document.addEventListener("keydown",...)

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dom, addeventlistener

I thought I should see how much I really need jQuery now. So I started by replacing

```
jQuery(document).on("keydown.", function(e){...})
```

with

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){...})
```

I believed that one was easy, but to my surprise the event was no longer fired. To investigate this a bit I entered the second version in the console. Now it worked. ;-)

That is a bit impractical, of course. I would prefer that I did not have to enter it in the console...

In the code the event listener is added right after some changes to the DOM, i e some additions. I guess the trouble might be related to this, but I have no idea what to do.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: Thanks everyone for the comments. In this particular case it would be good to get rid of jQuery (but otherwise it is no problem using jQuery of course).

I should have said that some DOM elements are added long after the page is loaded so window.onload etc is not useful here.

I should maybe also have said that I am testing this in the latest version of Chrome and for this I am not interested in backward compatibility (it is too complicated anyway in this case so I have just dropped that... ;-) ).

UPDATE: Someone asked for code. Here is an example I just tested:

```
    document.addEventListener("keydown.test", function(e){
        console.log("doc.addEL test keydown, e=", e)
    });
```

Looking in Chrome Dev Tools at the properties of the HTML element I can see the event listener there (with the code above). It is just not fired. Seems like it is just time to write yet another bug report then. ;-)

Comment: Maybe your code had errors in it, you should post it.

Comment: *"I thought I should see how much I really need jQuery now..."* You don't **need** jQuery. You may *want* it. I certainly do, I can't be bothered reinventing all of that utility functionality; testing it on umpteen browsers; discovering, working out the details of, and working around browser inconsistencies; proactively testing new browser releases within a day or two of release on thousands of different environments; creating a huge array of add-ons to do useful things... I mean...I have things to do. ;-)

Comment: On older browsers (IE<9) you should use `attachEvent` in combination with `addEventListener`

Comment: Try running it inside `window.onload = function() {}` wrapper.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: If the quoted jQuery version didn't need that, the `addEventListener` version doesn't.

Comment: @T.JCrowder Agreed, 32kb well spent and with the CDNs its most likely be cached.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder right, just confirmed in jsfiddle. Still, good practice to have JS code inside onload as usually one will access DOM elements in there.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: It's not good practice at all, the `load` event doesn't fire until all other resources have loaded (including all images). Good practice is to put your script tag at the end of the HTML, just before the closing `</body>` tag. ([Link](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom)) All of the elements are ready then, no need to wait for `load` (or `DOMContentLoaded`).

Answer (score 0):

My bad. I misread the news that event handlers now can be removed using standard syntax. They can, but the syntax is that you give the event+handler function to removeEventListener.

The syntax I used above for the event, "keydown.test", is not a valid syntax (if you are not using jQuery).

Sorry for wasting your time. Hope someone can use the answer.